# Apache Camel reading/writing to/from Input Stream

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am currently trying to use Apache Camel to decrypt a PGP encrypted file which has been loaded into an InputStream. The current problem I am facing is that the CamelContext appears to be hanging once started, as if it is continuously reading from `direct:is` after exhausting the stream. I followed [Apache Camel - how to use InputStream as source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420333/apache-camel-how-to-use-inputstream-as-source) to reach the point of possibly loading the given InputStream into the input channel.

```
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("direct:is")
                    .unmarshal().pgp(secretKeyFileName, keyUserId, keyPassword)
                    .to("direct:os")
                    .process(exchange -> latch.countDown());
        }
    });

    DefaultFluentProducerTemplate.on(context).withBody(inputStream).to("direct:is");
    DefaultFluentProducerTemplate.on(context).withBody(outputStream);
    context.start();
    latch.await();
    context.stop();
```

Comment: Have you tried `producerTemplate`? `producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:is", inputSteam);` [see an example here](https://github.com/Paizo/SpringBootCamelStreamsExample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/paizo/balance/controller/HomeController.java)